# Execute ffmpeg thought dart process take over a sec

Tags: dart, ffmpeg, process

I tried to execute the same command in cmd/powershell,they just take ~400ms.
I also tried to execute other program thought dart process with run or start method.they are fine.

But once I start ffmpeg process, it will take a sec to warmup…even the log level is quiet, even the input parameter is empty.

At the end the ffmpeg execution time+warmup time will cost 1400ms.

Does anyone has familiar issue? Is fixable?

Comment: i check the same code in my other pc, it just take 50ms to call ffmpeg process. So, it my first pc env issue.

Comment: Well, when I close the windows 10 defender every thing works fine, and the initial time down to 36ms. What will happen when I release my program to others, the defender check for a sec again?